# Can't connect client to Tridion Content Porter 2009 SP1 on Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

I'm trying to connect Content Porter 2009 SP1 client to a Tridion 2011 SP1 Content Manager, but I get an error when testing the connection.

I just installed the Content Porter Server on the Content Manager and downloaded/installed the Content Porter Client from the Content Manager.  After I configure the Content Manager's address in the client and try to authenticate to do an export, I get an error saying, "Could not find SDL Content Porter 2009 SP1 server on SDL Tridion Content Manager server ".

The client log has the following entry:

> 4/18/2012 10:06:15 PM  [Critical]  Test Connection returned an error
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Could not load type 'Tridion.Licensing.LicenseManager' from assembly 'Tridion.Common, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53'.
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.InvokeAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)

I have verified the cp_license.xml and license.xml are both present on the Content Manager.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a hotfix. Login to SDLTridionWorld.com, go to Downloads -> Hotfixes -> Content Porter 2009 SP1, then download (and install) hotfix CP_3.1.0.75326.

This should get you going.

Comment: Had the same issue and the can confirm the hotfix fixed the issue!